# Arduino IDE library location

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I have Arduino project WiFiManager that uses ArduinoJson 5. ArduinoJson is installed in my system and project compiles fine:
[image]

I decided to move to VisualStudio Code IDE. For this reason I need to copy library ArduinoJson 5 from Arduino IDE. I found `/Users/<username>/Documents/Arduino/` libraries in my Windows 10 machine. But there is no ArduinoJson 5 library. Where it is located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Arduino manual:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/hacking/libraries

> User-created libraries as of version 0017 go in a subdirectory of your
>   default sketch directory. For example, on OSX, the new directory would
>   be ~/Documents/Arduino/libraries/. On Windows, it would be My
>   Documents\Arduino\libraries. To add your own library, create a new
>   directory in the libraries directory with the name of your library.
>   The folder should contain a C or C++ file with your code and a header
>   file with your function and variable declarations. It will then appear
>   in the Sketch | Import Library menu in the Arduino IDE.
>
> Note: for users of versions previous to 0017, libraries belong in a
>   subdirectory of the Arduino application directory:
>   ARDUINO/lib/targets/libraries. For version 0017, the libraries
>   directory was moved to make them more convenient to install and use.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Libraries

> **Please note:** Arduino libraries are managed in three different places:
>   inside the IDE installation folder, inside the core folder and in the
>   libraries folder inside your sketchbook.

For cores refer to https://www.arduino.cc/en/guide/cores